# Can't install firestore

Tags: python, firebase, raspberry-pi, pip, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to install it on my RPi Zero W using
"sudo pip install --upgrade firebase-admin" / "sudo pip install firebase-admin",

but it keeps getting stuck at this point :

```
Installing collected packages: grpcio
  Running setup.py install for grpcio
```

and it just won't get past it, no matter how much time I wait.

Couldn't find any helpful answer for this,
tried installing grpcio alone,
tried installing without using cache,
any idea could help solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Can you rerun the command, but this time adding `-vvv` to it?

Comment: Fantastic! that took a while, but worked, thank you very much! What does -vvv do btw?

Comment: Eh? it worked now? Didn't know I can do magic! :-) `-vvv` just increases the verbosity level so you get more verbose output. I asked for this because I thought there may be some more info printed in the verbose mode, to see where the build gets stuck. But glad it worked for you now :-)

Comment: Yeah well aslong as it works ;) thx again :)